# Pasting the Location of a Cell in Another Worksheet - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here is how my code currently works:

On sheet 1 at location B5, the value of the cell is Dog. On sheet 2, C15, the paste location, the value is also Dog.

What I would like is for C15 to be =$B$5. This way, I can change B5 on just sheet 1 and C15 on sheet 2 changes as well.

I thought I could use a paste special but can't find any that would work since it's not really a paste function.

I thought I could maybe use this:

```
Sheets("Projects").Range(LastRow, "B").Value =_ 
Sheets("Database").Range(Newproject - Masterrow + 1, "C").Value
```

But it did not work, and so I'm here...

Current code:
Code:

```
Sub FindProjectName() 
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Newproject As Long
Dim MasterTemplate As Range
Dim Masterrow As Long


'MasterTemplate is the database entry template.
Masterrow = Worksheets("Database").Range("MasterTemplate").Rows.Count 
LastRow = Sheets("Projects").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 
Newproject = Sheets("Database").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 


Sheets("Projects").Cells(LastRow, "B").Copy Sheets("Database").Cells(Newproject - Masterrow + 1, "C") 


With Sheets("Database")
    .Range("DBASE").Rows(1).Copy 
    .Range("DBASE").Rows(Newproject - Masterrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
End Sub
```

I can't just use =SheetName!B5 for example because the template is copied to a new location everytime the code runs. I tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will accomplish what you described in the first part of your question. Once you understand how it works, I think you'll be able to apply it to your situation.  If not, feel free to ask questions.

```
Sub formulaTest()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set r1 = sh1.Range("B5")
r1 = "Dog"
Set r2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C15")
r2.formula = "=" & sh1.Name & "!" & r1.Address
End Sub
```

Here's the code you supplied in a followup comment along with an animated gif showing it working (except for overwriting the last item, "6")

```
Sub formulaTester()
Dim Feeder As Worksheet
Dim OneCell As Range
Dim TwoCell As Range
Set Feeder = Sheets("Projects")
Set OneCell = Feeder.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
OneCell = "Cow"
Set TwoCell = Sheets("Tester2").Range("C17")
TwoCell.formula = "=" & Feeder.Name & "!" & OneCell.Address
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your version and it worked flawlessly, then I tried my version and it didn't work:  `Sub formulaTester() </br>
Dim Feeder As Worksheet  
Dim OneCell As Range  
Dim TwoCell As Range  

Set Feeder = Sheets("Projects")  
Set OneCell = Feeder.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

OneCell = "Cow"  

Set TwoCell = Sheets("Tester2").Range("C17")  
TwoCell.Formula = "=" & Feeder.Name & "!" & OneCell.Address
End Sub`

Comment: Also, please, how do I add line breaks so my responses are easier to read?

Comment: This forum has advanced editing reserved for the purpose of clear questions & answers. The comments are not intended for detailed discussions nor formatted text.  It's done this way so that in the future people can search for specific answers to their questions without getting confused over discussions which go a zillion directions. I suggest you ask several specific questions, moving on after rewarding those who answer each time. This way all benefit. Just use the comments if you need a follow-up point clarified. By the way, I tried your code and it worked except OneCell overwrote an item

Comment: I added a demonstration of your working code at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: @Tony_M, Thank you for your help. One final question on this. Instead of ="Cow", can I use a cell address? My target cell is always moving and I am aiming at a target that is also always moving. I can't test those yet because I have something else broken in the code...

Comment: In brief, "no". Excel cells have many properties. ="Cow" is really inserting "Cow" into the VALUE property of the cell. But I believe the property you need here is the FORMULA property. There are many other properties which you can see when doing a Paste Special..., such as the COMMENT property. Each is distinct and cannot be used for other purposes. I think you'll get the most benefit from this site if you formulate each question into small pieces and make progress step by step to your goal. Each time please mark the Answered check mark to help others and reward the answerer.